# Is gazebo ros packages available for Gazebo7 and ROS Jade now?

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

My Ubuntu version is 15.04 with ROS Jade. Initially there is Gazebo 5 but I just wonder whether I should install Gazebo 7 or not. On one hand, I want to take advantage of the new features of Gazebo 7. On the other hand I am not sure if a gazebo-ros packages for ROS Jade and Gazebo 7 is available because the integration of Gazebo and ROS is of great importance to me. And help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12733/is-gazebo-ros-packages-available-for-gazebo7-and-ros-jade-now?/) by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 449 on 2016-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yes, it is. Just type these commands in the terminal to install gazebo7-related packages with ROS Jade:
`sudo apt-get install ros-jade-gazebo7-msgs`
`sudo apt-get install ros-jade-gazebo7-ros`
`sudo apt-get install ros-jade-gazebo7-plugins`
`sudo apt-get install ros-jade-gazebo7-ros-pkgs`

---

Originally posted by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) with karma: 449 on 2016-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2016-11-19**:
Note that the ros-jade-gazebo7-ros-pkgs package is a meta-package that will install the other three. Also remember to setup the packages.osrfoundation.org repo in order to use them. Full information is available in the tutorial: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions&cat=connect_ros